# React material-table: Change tree expand icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, material-table

I am using Material-table and especially Tree-data:
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/tree-data.

As I am implementing the exact example I cannot receive my arrow icon. It is like:

[image]

Could you tell me what I should pass into icons'object so it could render the right arrow + the down arrow when it is opened?
Previous I had the same problem with sorting arrow but later I found that I should pass SortArrow to icons property of MaterialTable component.

Answer (score 0):

Try **importing the icons stylesheet** to your `index.html` like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

For more details on **importing icons** (**alternate ways**), you can check the following link:
https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#installation

And as for how to render **specific icons**, you can check the following link:
https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/#material-icons

(P.S. As far as I recall, there are default icons already set to material-table. So unless you need to customize icons, importing only the stylesheet should suffice.)

Comment: Nope. I found the answer and will post it. It is possible to use icons property to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches I found that I can put **DetailPanel** in my icons property:

```
import { ChevronRight } from "@material-ui/icons";

    icons={{
            DetailPanel: ChevronRight,
          }}
```

So this makes table like:

[image]